# Highlight row if ID is found on other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have one Excel file that contains 2 worksheets.

Worksheet 1 columns:

```
computernames  Username   E-Mail

comp1  username mail@mail.de
comp2  username2 mail2@mail.de
```

---

Worksheet 2 columns:

```
computernames   Reason

comp2  "no antivirus"
```

My target is to highlight the row in Worksheet 1 if the computername exists in XLS Worksheet 2.

I did try the text based conditional formatting but it does not work because you can not search for a array on a array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a helper column, let's suppose it is *column E*. On cell E2 you must put: `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$30,1,FALSE)))`

where `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$30`is the column of values on worksheet 2.

Copy the formula along the column E.

Now on cell *A2* open conditional formatting, use formula and it must be `=$E2`. Test it. If succesful then use the copy format tool (*brush*) to copy the conditional formatting to all the other cells on worksheet 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i was not aware that it is not possible without a helper column.